# Load jqGrid subgrid with multilevel JSON data

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that loads subgrid data from an API. Everything loads in the subgrid just fine except for data that is a second level deep.

In my config for the main grid the options relating to the subgrid are set as:

```
    jsonReader: {
      // instruct subgrid to get the data as name:value pair
      subgrid: {
        repeatitems: false
      }
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subGridUrl: 'http://localhost:8081/api/addendums/',
    subGridModel: [{
      name: ['staff name', 'CDCR Staff', 'CDCR Staff Phone', 'notificationDate', 'comment'],
      mapping: ['staff.name', 'CDCRStaff', 'CDCRStaffPhone', 'notificationDate', 'comment'],
      width: [10, 55, 200, 80, 80]
    }],
    subGridOptions: {
      // configure the icons from theme rolloer
      plusicon: "fa fa-plus",
      minusicon: "fa fa-minus",
      openicon: ""
    }
```

The data that is loading for the subgrid is

```
{"rows": [
  {
    "id": 5,
        "AODId": 1,
        "staff": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Englebert Humperdink"
        },
        "CDCRStaff": "Col. Sanders",
        "CDCRStaffPhone": "916 233 1353",
        "notificationDate": "",
        "comment": "It really actually wasn't that bad"
      },
      {
    "id": 15,
        "AODId": 1,
        "staff": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Englebert Humperdink"
        },
        "CDCRStaff": "Col. Sanders",
        "CDCRStaffPhone": "916 233 1353",
        "notificationDate": "",
        "comment": "Upon further inspection, it was even worse than originally believed."
      },
      {
    "id": 51,
        "AODId": 1,
        "staff": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Sillybad Fumberwald"
        },
        "CDCRStaff": "Major Payne",
        "CDCRStaffPhone": "916 239 3903",
        "notificationDate": "",
        "comment": "This guy really doesn't know what he's talking about."
      }
]}
```

The subgrid gets the CDCRStaff, CDCRStaffPhone, notificationDate, and comment properties just fine, but it can not map to the name property inside the staff object. Is this a limitation with the subgrid functionality or is something set up wrong?

Comment: In Guriddo jqGrid this was a bug and I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to change format of the data to have flat structure of items and to use no dot separated names in `mapping`. Only if you can't change the data you can normilize the input data inside of `jsonReader.subgrid.root` defined as function. The corresponding code could the about the following:

```js
jsonReader: {
    subgrid: {
        root: function (data) {
            data.rows.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.staff != null) {
                    item["staff.name"] = item.staff.name;
                }
            });
            return data.rows;
        },
        repeatitems: false
    }
}
```